# Oracle trigger that inserts row after update

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert

I am trying to create a trigger (or something alike) that inserts a new row when one row is updated. 
The scenario is: I have a table of tasks that should be done every month. When a task  is set to completed (this is the update statement) i want a new task to be created, with the same parameters but a diferent date.
So I was thinking of an after update trigger that fires an insert statement onto the same table, but oracle won't allow this.

What is a good way to achive this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are encountering? If it's mutating table, there are workarounds but they are clumsy. See [this AskTom thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866) if you really want to do it. However I would recommend against triggers unless absolutely necessary. As long as we're linking to Tom Kyte, see his article "[The Trouble with Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)".

What you could do is in your code that executes the update, simply execute an insert after when the status is set to completed. I think that is a much better solution unless something precludes it.